# Error when using SOAP service in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, soap

When I use SOAP service using plain PHP code, it is working, but when I embed the same PHP code in CodeIgniter view file, showing error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function __soapCall() on a non-object in /home/content/r/a/m/ramlinux/html/Projects/LeadControlSystem/LCS_application_7/views/adminpanel/lead_email_scrub.php on line 49

code line 49:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall("VerifyEmail", array($params), null, null, $output_header);
```

Whats wrong with this line of code?

Comment: How is `$client` object initiated?

Comment: $WSDL = 'http://ws.sampledomain.com/EmailVerify5?WSDL';

$client = new SoapClient($WSDL, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1));

Comment: Do you actually get a proper soap object? Can you `print_r` or `var_dump` the `$client` variable after initiation?

Comment: When I print the $client object, it produces:

SoapClient Object ( [trace] => 1 [_soap_version] => 1 [sdl] => Resource id #42 )

Comment: hmm.. not sure, probably a typo on the variable name? Can't do much debugging without having at least few more lines of code - perhaps update the question..